# How can I have two columns in SQL Server auto increment?

Tags: sql-server, auto-increment

I have two columns in a table of a SQL server DB that I would like to autoincrement when new fields are added. However, Managment Studio wont allow me to set two columns to IDENTITY. Is there some other way to do this?

Comment: did you want those 2 columns to have the same value upon creation, or would they have different seeds?

Comment: I'm not really the one developing this database...I've already asked why we even need to ID fields, and a I think we're starting to realize that we don't. Although still I was curious how you would do it.

Comment: I'm mystified why you would ever need this -- can you enlighten?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking: adding a "field" (column) to a table sounds like a DDL operation to change the schema, are you expecting to change a column in every row when that happens?  If you are talking about a column changing from NULL to something else, that could maybe be a trigger which increments a revision column in the row - but you wouldn't want to use an IDENTITY for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make the second field a calculated field based on the first.

Or make an INSERT trigger than programatically generates the value for the second.

Comment: Yeah I think the trigger would probably be the best option. It doesn't need to follow any specific formula.

Comment: The problem with triggers is that they are slow.

Answer (score 4):

If you wanted the 2nd column to basically be a mirror of the first:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.myTable ADD
   foo  AS [rowid]
GO
```

If you wanted it to apply some math formula to it to achieve some kind of offset:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.myTable ADD
    foo  AS ([rowid]+1) * 7 --or whatever you like.
GO
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. These methods has concurrency issues? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There can only be one auto increment field per table. But, you could have a calculated field based on the auto increment field. Or, you could have an int field where you manage the sequence by front end code or by a trigger. And also you could use a [sequence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx) in SQL Server.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE MySequence START WITH 100;

CREATE TABLE MyTable
(
    RealIdentity INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    RandomCol NVARCHAR(100),
    FakeIdentity INT DEFAULT NEXT VALUE FOR MySequence
);
```

Comment: I think this is useful because sequences are what most people having similar questions may need in fact - they might be the only ones to satisfy all of their needs and in an efficient way / the way they expect. I think this might be the best solution. Thank you!